# System.out.flush does not work in Apache Netbeans IDE?

Tags: java

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class TestClass{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.print("input a string:  ");
        System.out.flush();
        Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
        s.next();
    }
}
```

The String "input a string:  " can not be printed to output window until I input a string.

Very confused.

Comment: I haved used two jdks: 14 and 15. But they have the same problem.

Comment: Java 11 seems to work okay

Comment: It is not about java jdk version.

But the problem of netbeans.

Comment: Yes, works in Netbeans 12.3, Java 11.0.1